# What are permissions are needed to upload a file via a public Salesforce community page?

Tags: community, permissions, security, upload

I would like to be able to upload files using `<lightning:fileUpload` which is on a **public** community page.

The community is using template: Customer Account Portal.

The files would get attached to a **custom** `Questionnaire` object.

What are the **minimum** permissions required on the custom `Questionnaire` object for the `Questionnaire` profile & user to be allowed to upload files via a **public** community page?

[image]

I've given the Guest Profile & User full permissions over the custom `Questionnaire` object and it still errors:

> There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again

And nothing appears in the Debug log.

Note: I mistakenly tested the public community using the same browser that I was logged in as Sys Admin, and it uploaded fine. But having tested again using Incognito mode, it does not upload.

Comment: Is this a customer or a partner community?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The component is now supported for guest users with **Spring '19**.

- [Let Community Guest Users Upload Files](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_upload.htm) release notes.

  > Promote file sharing in your communities. Let guest users upload files using the `lightning:fileUpload` component.
- From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) for the component:

  > By default, guest users can’t upload files. You can enable the org preference `Allow site guest users to upload files`.

---

This section was relevant in Winter '19, removed now as the support is now available with Spring '19.

<s>Based on the latest updated question.</s>

`lightning:fileUpload` is **not supported** for **Guest Users**. Refer to the below excerpt from [**documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation).

> Guest users can't add files to Communities.

<s>Your only option here may be to utilize a VF page (as mentioned by Pranay in the [other answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/240898/54851))</s>

---

The **[documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation)** for `lightning:fileUpload` mentions the following:

> File uploads are always associated to a record, hence the recordId attribute is required

And based on the [**help article**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_attach_records.htm&type=5), if you need to attach a file to a record, you will at least need a READ access on the object.

[image]

Comment: Probably worth looking here as well, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/204662/19118

Comment: I've set those permissions and it still will not upload.

Comment: I mistakenly tested the public community using the same browser that I was logged in as Sys Admin, and it uploaded fine. But having tested again using Incognito, it does not upload.

Comment: @Robs unfortunately, it seems you cannot utilize `lightning:fileUpload` component here for Guest Users. The component is not supported for that scenario. Refer to the updates in my answer.

Comment: It is available as of Spring '19: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_upload.htm

Comment: @RobinDeBondt Thanks for sharing this. At the time of writing, it was not available in Winter '19.

Comment: This is interesting... Would have saved me doing a circus.

Comment: @Robs, if you are still looking for a solution using the component, Spring '19 now has it.

Answer (score 6):

**Attempt 1:**

As it was not possible via profiles, I tried doing it via permission set.

I created a new permission set and added below permission for files

1. Create Content Deliveries
2. Create Public Links
3. Moderate Communities Files

And when I tried to assign that permission set to the guest site user, here is the error I get.

It didn't let me assign permission set till I removed all the above 3 permissions.

```
Can't save permission set AA, which is assigned to a user with user license Guest User License. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Create Content Deliveries
Can't save permission set AA, which is assigned to a user with user license Guest User License. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Create Public Links 
Can't save permission set AA, which is assigned to a user with user license Guest User License. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Moderate Communities Files
```

Salesforce is not willing to allow Files via guest user context and hence it will fail with all the standard methods possible.

### [image]

**Attempt 2:**: If I cannot use lightning, let me revert back to visualforce page.

I created a Page and VF controller:

```
<apex:page controller="ContentController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:inputFile value="{!file}" />
    <apex:commandbutton action="{!upload}" value="Upload" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class ContentController {
    public blob file { get; set; }

    public PageReference upload() {
        ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion();
        v.versionData = file;
        v.title = 'testing upload';
        v.pathOnClient ='/somepath.txt';
        insert v;
        return new PageReference('/' + v.id);
    }
}
```

And then used my Community builder to drag and drop that VF page on my Guest access site. I assigned VF page and controller access via Guest User Profile. I published it and then tested in an incognito window

And **voila**, I was able to upload file and generate an ID for it using visualforce and Apex.

**Only Drawback**: Less than 6MB can only be uploaded. Happy days.

[image]

Comment: May I know how can we relate the file to any record which is uploaded by the guest user?

Comment: I am trying to achieve same functionality. I have created a custom object and gave permissions to guest user profile to it.
Created a ltg fileupload component and it works perfectly fine for logged in user.
I have enabled to guest site file upload settimg as well.
When i try in incognito mode, it still gives me ‘cant upload filename.ext’ error. What else could i be missing? I am using custom template in communities and i have enterprise edition license. Thanks
Nike

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jayant Das.

As of **Salesforce Spring ’19 Release** you can now enable **Allow site guest users to upload files**

[image]

**Reference**

- [Release notes: Let Community Guest Users Upload Files](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_upload.htm)

Comment: I was assuming this would fix the issue, but yet it's not working, we expect the same 'Can't upload xyz file' error. I have a opened case with Salesforce and they're still working on figuring out what is needed to enable the feature for guest community user. would come back here to update if I get a positive feedback.

Comment: @PasanEeriyagama did you get a response on this?  It works for me if I grant Read Only sharing to the record but I really don't want to have to do this as I don't know the record the guest is trying to access before hand, and on top of that, its not mentioned in the docs!

Comment: Hi @ministe2003 yes, in my scenario, simply included 'With sharing' in class definition and that fixed the issue for me. cheers!