# Public Page: Lightning Upload not attaching documents

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

We are working in lightning and created a flow to upload files. when we are calling the flow in visualforce page and using the page on a public website,
its upload file functionality is not working on public website page. (we can select the file by clicking on upload files but upload functionality not working).Can anyone suggest me how to resolve it or is it a known issue?

[image]

**Lightning App - AutomationPublicFormsCompApp.app**

```
<aura:application access="Global" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:flow"/>
</aura:application>
```

**VF page**

```
 <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <head>
    <apex:includeLightning />
  </head>
  <body class="slds-scope">
    <div style="margin-left: 100px;margin-right: 280px;">
      <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Pre_employ_logo}" Style="width: 200px;"/>
      <div id="flowContainer" />
      <div id="lightning" />
      <div Style="width: 330px; margin-left: 315px; height: 60px;"><h1> © 2019 Pre-employ.com, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</h1></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var url = window.location.toString();
      var fields = url.split('=');
      var vTicketID = fields[1];
      if(vTicketID.includes('&')) {
        vTicketID = vTicketID.split('&');
        vTicketID = vTicketID[0];
      }
      var inputVariables = [
          { name : "varTicketID", type : "String", value: vTicketID }
      ];
      var statusChange = function (event) {
        if(event.getParam("status") == "FINISHED") {
          var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
          var key;
          for(key in outputVariables) {
            if(outputVariables[key].name == "myOutput") {}
          }
        }
      };
      $Lightning.use("c:AutomationPublicFormsCompApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {"onstatuschange":statusChange}, "flowContainer",
          function (component) {
            component.startFlow("Automation_Test_Flow_Public_Forms", inputVariables);
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

**Successful upload message box which is not coming while adding the file from public site:**

[image]

Comment: not working is not very descriptive, have you managed to pinpoint exactly what part of your code is not working? any debugging?

Comment: Actually, I am calling the visual flow "Automation_Test_Flow_Public_Forms" from lightning component and passing the parameter "inputVariables". At the time of running the flow  independently it works fine but when we are calling the flow in the visualforce page and using the page on a public website, its upload file functionality is not working. I am adding the successful upload confirmation box at the end of the question.(which is not coming after selecting the file)

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/223570/19118

Comment: I thought that public pages were VF only....Where can I find documentation on how to use lightning? The sites gives me only VF pages to add. I have a feeling I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @disasterlooms If you look at this code, you'll notice this is actually a VF page that's dynamically generating Lightning components.  In this line of code: `$Lightning.use("c:AutomationPublicFormsCompApp", function() { /* ... */ })`

Comment: @Pranay Jaiswal Link you mention shows permission issue while I am not getting the upload message box and also i used visual flow to upload file not "lightning:fileUpload" component.