# Chatter Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) when uploading a file as community guest user

Tags: community, guest-user, fileupload

**Background**

I am uploading a file as a community guest user, but I am getting this error message:

> There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again.

Displayed here:

[image]

And this error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

from this URL:

```
/pagename/chatter/handlers/chatterfile?auraXhr=true
```

I have enabled the `Allow site guest users to upload files` feature in:

```
Setup > General Files Settings
```

And according to the release note [Let Community Guest Users Upload Files](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_upload.htm) this is all I need to do to enable upload as a community guest user.

The `<lightning:fileUpload` is configured as below:

```
<lightning:fileUpload name="fileUploader" 
     label="Upload File" 
     multiple="false"
     recordId="{!v.defaultUploadRecordID}"
     onuploadfinished="{! c.handleUploadFinished }" />
```

The `recordId` value `defaultUploadRecordID` is definitely set.

The `defaultUploadRecordID` is set to the `RecordId` of a custom object.

The `Site Guest User` has full permissions over the custom object.

`Feed Tracking` is enabled for the object the upload is being attached to.

The community has a file upload limit of `6 MB` and allows `.pdf` files to be uploaded.

I've tried hardcoding the `recordID` and it still fails.

If I run the page as `System Administrator` it works fine.

**Questions**

1. What is causing the error?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: did you look at [your own question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222577/what-are-permissions-are-needed-to-upload-a-file-via-a-public-salesforce-communi)

Comment: @RedDevil thank you for trying to help, but yes I had looked at that, which is why my question is so detailed.

Comment: my intention was to say there is information in that question, my apologies if it came out as rude. This aside, i tried uploading files using the tag to a contact and once i enabled guest user access to file and read access to contact for guest user it worked perfectly. Did you check network of chrome to see if browser is showing an error in xhr response

Comment: @RedDevil thanks, are you able to upload the file and attach it to the guest user?

Comment: Yes it shows the owner as testguestaccess Site Guest User. I can list what i did if you want

Comment: @RedDevil are you setting `recordId` to the `user.Id` of the `Site Guest User`?

Comment: I used contact id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93632/discussion-between-robs-and-reddevil).

Comment: @Robs Have you tried to reach out to Salesforce Support on this?

Comment: @JayantDas yes, but no response yet, and I don't have developer level support so I will most likely be told they won't help...

Comment: @Robs I will try it out sometime today and will definitely come back and let you know what I find.

Comment: @Robs I just spun off a public community and used a custom lightning component, and was able to upload the file. https://jdcommunity-developer-edition.ap15.force.com/napili/s/ if you want to try. I already have a record id specified in the component and could verify that the uploaded file is available on the record.

Comment: @JayantDas yes, @RedDevil was able to do the same, but when I went on a screen share with him and replicated his config and used his code it did not work, and I get the 401 error `/pagename/chatter/handlers/chatterfile?auraXhr=true` in the console.

Comment: Sorry @Robs it didn't work for you. It's really hard to tell in that case as it seems there is something else going on. Do you have a trigger or any other validation by any chance on Files?With what you have here, it worked perfectly fine with the test I did.

Comment: @JayantDas would you be open to a screen share to review the settings?

Comment: @Robs. I found [this here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pad4QAA) which exactly seems to be your case. Support needs to be engaged for sure -- *The permission "Changed Decoupled upload support for ContentVersion (Files)" which was previously disabled on your org which causing this issue, We have enabled this permission now which fixed this, This enabling can done at our end I suggest whenever you face this issue I request you to log a case with sales force with reference to this case number So that we can take it from there*