# How to add an onchange event to a <input type="file"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-community

I am unable to get a `<lightning:fileUpload>` to work on a public community page, so I need to write a custom upload component.

I want to fire an `onchange` event after the user selects a file using:

```
<input aura:id="file" />
```

I've tried:

```
<input aura:id="file" onchange="{!c.handleFileSelected}" />
```

And in the `doInit` controller method:

```
var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
fileInput.addEventListener("onchange", helper.handleFileSelected);
```

And

```
var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
fileInput.onchange = helper.handleFileSelected;
```

And

```
var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
fileInput.addEventListener("onchange",$A.getCallback(helper.handleFileSelected));
```

But none of these solutions work.

Most of them result in the element not appearing on the page.

**Question**

1. How can I add an `onchange` event to the input?

Comment: Inside doInit, the elements may not be rendered yet (I'm pretty sure they're not). Maybe move this to the `render()` function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to @sfdcfox, for the recommendation to use the `render()` method.

**FileUploadRenderer.js**

```
({
    render: function (component, helper) {
        var returnVal = this.superRender();
        var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
        fileInput.onchange = helper.handleFileSelected;
        return returnVal;
    }
})
```

In the end I used this:

```
({
    render: function (component, helper) {
        var returnVal = this.superRender();
        var fileInput = component.find("file").getElement();
        fileInput.onchange = $A.getCallback(helper.handleFileSelected.bind(helper, component));
        return returnVal;
    }
})
```

So that I have access to `component` in the `handleFileSelected` method

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you instead use a [`<lightning:fileUpload>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation) component and its `onuploadfinished` attribute.

> This example creates a file uploader that allows multiple PDF and PNG files to be uploaded. Change the recordId value to your own.
>
> ```
> <aura:component>
>     <aura:attribute name="myRecordId" type="String" description="Record to which the files should be attached" />
>     <lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt"
>         name="fileUploader"
>         multiple="true"
>         accept=".pdf, .png"
>         recordId="{!v.myRecordId}"
>         onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
> </aura:component>
> ```

Comment: I cannot get `<lightning:fileUpload` to work in the context of a public community page, please see this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262268/chatter-error-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-40). I need an alternative solution.